# Plugin I created is asking for a license key

Tags: plugin-development

I created a plugin for a client website and I keep getting license issues popping up in the admin panel for it. Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Obviously I have no intention of putting it into the store, I just want to remove this license key issue.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Craft checks only the `handle` of your plugin to detect license mismatches. So when your plugin has the handle `importer` and another plugin in the store has the same handle it will mark it. (since importer is already a plugin in the store it's likely the issue)

The only ways to solve it

1. change your handle to `data-importer` or whatever might be unique
2. make a module out of it
3. (include CSS to remove the message and ignore it)

Comment: Of course this is correct. It's a Robin Schambach answer.

Comment: Is it only necessary to change the handle of it in the composer.json? I think I went through too much work and just created a new plugin scaffold and move my code into that one. Seems like a lot of unnecessary work.

Comment: It is enough to change the handle in the composer file unless you used the handle in your code as an identifier for example `\Craft::$app->getPlugins()->getPlugin('importer')` you'll need to change those as well. Keep in mind once installed, Craft will cache your composer file so you need to remove the plugin entirely until you are able to change the handle (or edit Crafts `Plugins.php` file)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you copied some code from another plugin?